# How do I crop a konva image when it has been resized?

Tags: javascript, image, konvajs, konva

In my project, I have a konva canvas where I can add items. I default these item images to a height and width of 200. When trying to apply a crop to the item, the crop ignores the resized image dimensions. It crops the image size to the correct height and width but the image itself returns back to its original dimensions. Is there an easy way to fix this? I saw this being asked [KonvaJS crop and resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798061/konvajs-crop-and-resize) but that deals with a manual resizing of images.

image when loaded with
original dimensions 394 x 387 that is resized to 200 x 200 image in a 200 x 200 area

[image]

when trying to crop the image of 8 pixels, the image reverts back to 394 x 387 and crops to 386 x 387 in an image area of 192 x 200

[image]

```
addItem = (imgUrl) => {
    const img = new (window as any).Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const width, height = 200;
      img.width = 200;
      img.height = 200;
      const newImg = new Konva.Image({ width, height, image: img, draggable: true });
      this.layer.add(newImg);
      this.layer.draw();
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
  }

cropItem = (item) => {
    item.crop({
      x: item.cropX() + 8,
      y: item.cropY() + 0,
      width: item.width() - 8,
      height: item.height() - 0
    });

    item.width(item.width() - 8);
    this.layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: So, your `cropItem` is already doing what you want. Am I right?

Comment: @lavrton nope, it doesn't crop with the resized dimensions of the image

Comment: Can you add online demo and clarify what exactly do you want to achieve? I still don't get it.
crop attributes of Image are related to image original size.

Comment: @lavrton I was able to solve the issue, to set the initial width height, I had to use scaleX and ScaleY. The actual image width and height are set to the original image width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use scaleX and scaleY

```
addItem = (imgUrl) => {
    const img = new (window as any).Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const { width, height } = image;
      const desiredWidth = 200;
      const desiredHeight = 200;
      const scaleX = desiredWidth / width;
      const scaleY = desiredHeight / height;
      const newImg = new Konva.Image({ width, height, image: img, scaleX, scaleY, draggable: true });
      this.layer.add(newImg);
      this.layer.draw();
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
  }
```